# How to trigger .click() on hidden element on Safari with React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

I have a button in React.js which one clicks sends data to the server to be converted into a CSV file. When I get the response, I want to be able to have the users download the CSV file. It works in Firefox and Chrome but not Safari. Any ideas? I know .click() is not supported on [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

import ExportDataQL from 'ExportDataQL'
import Icon from 'Icon';

const handleExport = (data, type, exportToCSV) => {
  const variables = { 
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type
  }

  exportToCSV({ variables })
  .then( response => {
    const { fileName, fileUri } = response.data.exportToCSV

    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = fileUri;
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement);
    console.log('clicking')
    // hiddenElement.click();
    hiddenElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(`click`, {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}))
    hiddenElement.remove()
  })
  .catch( e => console.log('ERROR getting download URL:', e) )
}

const ExportToCSV = ({ data, dataType, buttonText, exportToCSV }) => {
  if (data === undefined || data.length===0) return <span></span>

  return <button
          type='button'
          className="btn btn-link hover_cursor font-weight-bold"
          onClick={() => handleExport(data, dataType, exportToCSV)}>
          <Icon IconClassName="fill-primary" icon='excel-file'/><span className="ml-2">
          {buttonText ? buttonText : "Export data"}</span>
        </button>
}


export default graphql(ExportDataQL.exportToCSV, {name: "exportToCSV"})(ExportToCSV);
```

Comment: Is the download supposed to be mandatory after a response is fetched? I can't really wrap my head around why you'd want a hidden element that you "click" to download a file to the client. Seems like an unnecessary hack :)

Comment: Have you tried the CSS cursor : 'pointer' fix already? This way safari should see it as a clickable thing.

Comment: @MstrQKN The button makes a call to the API to which processes the data and returns the CSV. I want the user to have to click only once. How can I have a button which calls the API then auto-downloads the CSV? Does that make sense? Maybe there is a better way of doing this.